# Отключить воспроизведение на сайте нескольких видео одновременно

Tags: javascript, html5

Имеется сайт. На сайте несколько видео. Например, я воспроизвел одно видео, и не нажимая паузы у первого, включаю второе и они оба работают. Как при нажатии следующего реализовать отключение предыдущего?

```html
<iframe width="50%" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wr-buV4tYOA" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="50%" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KNDT7EInclo" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Не знаю, у всех ли так, у меня не работают видео на данном сайте. Кидаю ссылку на Codepen: https://codepen.io/Kreami/pen/OvppBp

Comment: Ну так как видео с youtube, то его можно контролировать через его API. https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference Если разберусь напишу пример.

Comment: Не обязательно с youtube. Возможно в дальнейшем буду подключать локально видео.

Comment: Ну так подключать можно по разному. Уникального способа контролировать видео вроде нет. Особенно если вы используете сторонний плеер.

Comment: По моему это довольно спорная реализация. Обычно делают так что видео воспроизводиться в одном месте. Пользователь только выбирает либо само видео, либо вариант плеера/озвучки если воспроизводится одно видео с разных ресурсов. Либо у сервиса есть собственный плеер с выбором серий, озвучки и пр.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы был доступ к функциям плеера youtube вам нужно добавлять видео динамически.

Сделал пример из двух видео. Когда пытаемся одно включить остальные ставятся на паузу. Здесь не работает поэтому вот тут рабочий вариант https://codepen.io/atributz/pen/WzpONq

```js
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads
   var array1=[];
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    
        array1[array1.length] = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '360',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
    });
    array1[array1.length] = new YT.Player('player2', {
          height: '360',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'JApOnppva1U',
          events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
    });
   }

      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == 1) {
     for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      if (array1[i]!=event.target) {
       //} else {
       array1[i].pauseVideo();
      }
     }
    }
      }
```

```html
<div id="player"></div>
<div id="player2"></div>
```

Comment: Есть еще вариант подключать видео не через js и ставить его на паузу с помощью вызова postMessage для соответствующего элемента. Но как тогда отслеживать состояние видео не ясно.  https://toster.ru/q/269765